# ¿ Es correcto añadir un `div` en un enlace?

Tags: css, html5, div, seo, enlaces-ancla

tengo unos iconos en mi sitio web, los cuales a través de bootstrap al pasar el ratón por encima, aumentan ligeramente el tamaño.
Los iconos están dentro de dos `div` mas.
Quiero que al pinchar en el icono, además de que estos aumenten de tamaño, me lleven a otra pagina mi sitio.
Les muestro uno de los `div`:

```
<section class="ulockd-service-three">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <div class="ulockd-srvc-column-two one text-center">
        <div class="ulockd-srvc-details-two">
          <div class="ulockd-srv-icon-two"><span class="flaticon work"> 
          </span>
          </div>
          <h5>Safety Work</h5>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

He probado varias formas de meter el enlace, y finalmente encontré una que me redirige a la pagina deseada, pero no se si es la forma mas correcta de hacerlo, no me parece que sea apropiado, no parece estético.

Asi me funciona el enlace:

```
<section class="ulockd-service-three">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <div class="ulockd-srvc-column-two one text-center">
        <div class="ulockd-srvc-details-two">
          <a href="about.html"><div class="ulockd-srv-icon-two">
            <span class="flaticon-work"> </span>
          </div></a>
          <h5>Safety Work</h5>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Lo que quiero decir es que si esta dentro de lo permitido, teniendo en cuenta todo, incluido si a Google le gustara o no.
¿ Pueden decirme la manera correcta de añadir un enlace al icono sin romper el efecto de aumento ?

Gracias

Comment: En HTML5 es correcto, antes no lo era. Puedes poner dentro de un enlace elementos de bloque: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#example-e6ee3b01

Comment: Gracias @blonfu , osea que ¿ Puedo seguir adelante con esa estructura ? Son varios los div a los que debo añadir un enlace interno. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta varía dependiendo de la versión de HTML que utilices:

- Si utilizas una versión anterior a HTML5, el contenido dentro de un enlace debería ser únicamente elementos inline.
- Si utilizas [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), un enlace puede contener párrafos enteros, listas, tablas, incluso secciones enteras.

Por lo tanto, si estas utilizando HTML5 tu caso es totalmente válido.